# RMarkdown Inline References do not show

Tags: r, reference, yaml, r-markdown

I want to make an inline reference list in my RMD, as explained in https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_bibliographies_and_citations.html . 
Unfortunately, the reference does not show. The code I have in the rmd:

```
---
output: pdf_document
references:
- id: fenner2012a
  title: One-click science marketing
  author:
  - family: Fenner
    given: Martin
  container-title: Nature Materials
  volume: 11
  URL: 'http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nmat3283'
  DOI: 10.1038/nmat3283
  issue: 4
  publisher: Nature Publishing Group
  page: 261-263
  type: article-journal
  issued:
    year: 2012
    month: 3
---

According to
https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_bibliographies_and_citations.html
I should have the example reference below

# References
```

Anyone an idea what I can do to let it show? It did work before, do not know exactly if this was before upgrading to R4. All packages are up to date (just did the update). RStudio version 1.2.5042. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you? ;)

```
---
output: pdf_document
references:
- id: fenner2012a
  title: One-click science marketing
  author:
  - family: Fenner
    given: Martin
  container-title: Nature Materials
  volume: 11
  URL: 'http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nmat3283'
  DOI: 10.1038/nmat3283
  issue: 4
  publisher: Nature Publishing Group
  page: 261-263
  type: article-journal
  issued:
    year: 2012
    month: 3
---

According to
https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_bibliographies_and_citations.html
I should have the example reference below

But only if we use the reference: [@fenner2012a]



# References
```